# Javascript overwriting childs references

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference, tree

Good night every one, im working on a class project, a tic-tact-toe IA that would never loss, i decided to change to minimax but while i was computing the game tree i got this strange behavior.

i was using a recursive function to fill a `board` with 9 spaces, starting from blank to full (i know this is sup optimal from tic-tact-toe) each run of the recursive function will start whit a fresh copy of the game board state (blank for the first) and return a `leaf` that has the board state and an array with the children leafs but the problem is that in some place the reference to the children leafs are being replaced whit the parent reference, so when I'm recursively traversing the tree eventually (and obviously)  I'm hitting the recursion limit and getting an `too much recursion` error on Firefox

## The Code:

first of all i'm using  John Resig's Class prototype and this is how the leaf class looks like:

```
Leaf = Class.extend({
    childs:null,

    init:function(){
        this.childs = new Array();
    },

    value:null,

    append:function (child){
        this.childs.push(child);
    },

    toString:function(){

        c = [];

        for(a in this.childs){
            s = this.childs[a].toString();//for some reason c wont append if is returned directly

            c.push(s);
        }

        return JSON.stringify({"value":this.value.toString(),"childs":JSON.stringify(c) });

    }

})
```

and this is the recursive function:

```
function make(board, player){
//board is an object wrapping an 2-dimensional array with 9 cells where
// 0 = open; 1 = player x; -1 = player o;
//player is an integer, 1 for x,-1 for o

    leaf = new Leaf;
    open = getOpen(board);

    while(open.length > 0){

        b = board.duplicate();

        o = open.pop();

        b.setPosition(a.x,a.y,player);

        n = make(t,jugador * -1 );

        leaf.append(n);

    }

    leaf.value = board;
    return leaf;

}
```

i have tested the tree by adding references by hand and it works, but here it just overwrites the children references.

so why are the references being changed (and where), i just cant answer this two questions

Comment: the variable is being overwriten becouse is an global variable, not a local variable, updating this latter